# Excel Mac 2011 VBA .interior crashes

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

A file that works fine in the Windows version of excel crashes when running on MacOffice 2011.  The file crashes when I try to set the cell color or font color, basically when I try to use range().interior.*  When I comment out interior property the VBA runs fine.  For instance the following code runs

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecasting").Range("H" & itemrangerow & ":AD" 
    & itemrangerow)
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .RowHeight = 15
    .Locked = False
    '.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    End With
```

While the below crashes

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecasting").Range("H" & itemrangerow & ":AD" & itemrangerow)
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .RowHeight = 15
    .Locked = False
    .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    End With
```

I have also tried taking the line out of the with statement by using

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecasting").Range("H" & itemrangerow & ":AD" & itemrangerow).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
```

But this still crashes.  Any ideas?

Comment: What error is it giving you? For fun, just try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecasting").Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)`...does that work?

Comment: I tried it but it still causes the same error: "Run time error'1004': The specified Dimension is not valid for the current chart type."

Comment: are you trying to do this on a chart? Also make sure you do have a sheet with that name.

Comment: No this is not on a chart, just a Range. The sheet exists and the range is valid as the borders on the range are updated correctly.  It only errors out on the .interior line  if I comment that out the rest works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it, thanks Batman! (I mean BruceWayne3)  There was a chart that was based on cells that referenced the cells that I was trying to format. Once I deleted that chart then I could format the cells as expected.  Huge thanks!

One more note for others: I would also get an error if the sheet was protected so I had to unprotect the sheet before the .interior and protect it again after.